# tweet button inside jquery template

Tags: twitter, jquery-templates

I want to integrate tweet button inside a jquery template. Am trying the 'tweet button with javascript' ([link](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button)). But my html template shows only link, it does not show the button. I tried the anchor tag outside the jquery-templ script. Then it is working fine. I am confused why this is not working inside jquery-tmpl.

code look like follows:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="twitterapi"   data-lang="en">Tweet</a>   

</script>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s) [0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the closing `</script>` tag is not parsed correctly by the browser.

You could write `</scr{{= ""}}ipt>` instead...

The point is, that browsers don't understand nesting of `<script>` tags, so whenever it parses a `</script>`, it closes the outermost script tag. Therefore, the closing `</script>` tag is matched to the template script.

You can trick the browser into ignoring the script tag, by adding the `{{= ""}}`, which will be used by the template engine to generate an empty string. `</scr{{= ""}}ipt>` will result in `</script>`, after templating.

Comment: Thanks Moritz for the reply. can you explain little bit? I tried but does not seems to be working!

Comment: Once again thanks Mortiz. I understand the problem now. But this is not working for my django app!. I think it is because of django's strong templating system.

Comment: The above answer is the common solution. Since { and } are reserved characters in Django templates, you have to use like                                                                   {% templatetag openbrace %}{% templatetag openbrace %}html "</sc"+"ript>"}{% templatetag closebrace %}{% templatetag closebrace %}   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382483/could-not-parse-the-reminder-in-django/10382510#10382510

Comment: I didn't know you were building a Django app.

Comment: yes Moritz. I were not mentioned that in question.I thought it was not related to Django(true though). But I got enough from you. Thanks!