# Could not parse the reminder in django

Tags: django, django-templates, jquery-templates

I want to add a script tag inside a jquery template. So am referring to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788525/script-tag-inside-jquery-template).
It tells to close the inner script tag in the following way :

```
<script id="filaVideoTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
    <!-- Some HTML here -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- Some javascript here -->
    {{html "</sc"+"ript>"}}
</script>
```

I tried it, but django shows this error: 
Could not parse the remainder: '" < /sc"+"ript>"' from 'html "< /sc"+"ript>"'

.How can I do this django. Is there any specific solution in django for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{` and `}` are reserved characters in Django templates, so you need to use [`templatetag`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag).

Replace:

```
{{html "</sc"+"ript>"}}
```

With:

```
{% templatetag openbrace %}{% templatetag openbrace %}html "</sc"+"ript>"{% templatetag closebrace %}{% templatetag closebrace %}
```

Comment: Hi Dominic, there is one unnecessary closing brace just after "</sc"+"ript>". Please remove it.